# How can I stop my iPhone (X) randomly connecting to my Bluetooth speakers?

Tags: iphone, audio, bluetooth

I have some Bluetooth enabled Klipsch speakers connected to my TV via ARC. When the TV is turned on, the speakers automatically come on and play the sound from the TV.

However, my iPhone then randomly connects to the speakers making them switch to Bluetooth, cutting the TV connection. This is really inconvenient if, say, my SO is watching TV and I'm in another room doing something else.

Worse still, if I'm listening to music with the phone connected to my Bluetooth headphones, the phone will still randomly switch to the speakers, cutting my headphone's connection and playing whatever I am listening to through the speakers (again, interrupting the TV).

I could have the phone 'forget' the speakers Bluetooth connection, but then I can't use my phone to play music from the speakers (without re-pairing them which involves digging around at the back of the speaker and holding down certain buttons for a certain amount of secounds) which is half the reason I bought them.

This is such a pain - I'm in the habit of having to turn off Bluetooth on the phone whenever I'm at home just to prevent this. Is there anyway to have the phone still remember the Bluetooth connection, but only connect when I want it to?